# Invalid object name 'INSERTED' - Trigger after INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, triggers

I've been trying to create a trigger in Microsoft SQL Server environement, but whatever I do I cannot get it to work.

I want to insert values from a **View** (Obowiązkowe_Przedmioty_Studentów) into a **Table** (Przedmioty_Studentów), **filtered by the NEW value** insterted into  **table** (Kierunki_Studentów).

It looks like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Przedmioty_Studenta_z_Kierunku
ON dbo.Kierunki_Studentów
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Przedmioty_Studentów
SELECT Id_Studenta, Id_Przedmiotu
FROM   Obowiązkowe_Przedmioty_Studentów ops
JOIN INSERTED i ON ops.Id_Studenta = i.Id_Studenta
WHERE (Id_Studenta = i.Id_Studenta) 
END
```

Before I just tried using:

```
WHERE (Id_Studenta = INSERTED.Id_Studenta)
```

But is just told me that "**it cannot be bound**". I looked at other posts here and there was an example with JOIN. I did the exact same thing as was there in the example, but now it spits out: "**Invalid object name 'INSERTED'**"

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Przedmioty_Studentów
        SELECT Id_Studenta, Id_Przedmiotu
        FROM Obowiązkowe_Przedmioty_Studentów ops JOIN
             inserted i
             ON ops.Id_Studenta = i.Id_Studenta;
END;
```

The `WHERE` clause is somewhere between ambiguous and redundant -- the `ON` clause does the matching.  Once you declare the alias `i` for `inserted`, you need to use `i` for the qualified column names.